# Lambda Function and NTLM

Tags: soap, aws-lambda, ntlm-authentication

I'm investigating to generate a Lambda Function (Java) with SOAP WSDL transfer protocol and NTLM as authentication protocol.
Could somebody tell me if is it possible? I've read that maybe it's no possible 'cause NTLM is not supported on Lambdas and we need to do a big workaround (maybe it's wrong)